# C parse dec to hex and output as char[]

Tags: c, hex

I need some help please. I am looking to modify the DecToHex function.

For input decimalNumber = 7 :

**Actual output :**

```
sizeToReturn = 2;
hexadecimalNumber[1] = 7;
hexadecimalNumber[0] = N/A ( is garbage );
```

**Desired output :**

```
sizeToReturn = 3
hexadecimalNumber[2] = 0
hexadecimalNumber[1] = 7
hexadecimalNumber[0] = N/A ( is garbage )
```

The function :

```
void DecToHex(int decimalNumber, int *sizeToReturn, char* hexadecimalNumber)
{
    int quotient;
    int i = 1, temp;
    quotient = decimalNumber;
    while (quotient != 0) {
        temp = quotient % 16;
        //To convert integer into character
        if (temp < 10)
            temp = temp + 48; else
            temp = temp + 55;
        hexadecimalNumber[i++] = temp;
        quotient = quotient / 16;
    }

    (*sizeToReturn) = i;
}
```

> This will append each u8 to an array :

```
for (int k = size - 1;k > 0;k--)
        AppendChar(Str_pst, toAppend[k]);
```

Comment: Please provide how you are expecting your output to look like.

Comment: After I call your function with DecToHex(7, &len, buff), the first character of buff is not '7' and the length is not 1, which is implied by your claim for what you get. The first character of buff is chr(200) and the second is chr(55).

Comment: What is your input and what are you trying to do it is not clear

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: `N/A ( is NOT garbage )` -- it's zero (or should be zero if you properly initialize`hexadecimalNumber`) you need to add `'0'` (e.g. 48) to it `:)` Also, why not simply perform the reversal in your function and return an in-order hexidecimal number through `hexadecimalNumber` and add a `0x` to your output in `main()` if you like?

Comment: The [0] index dosn't matter anyway. "why not simply perform the reversal in your function" ... because the function dos not add any 0 to the array. The best example is '\0'. Function will return 1 ( that actually means 0 because the first bit dosnt count ). Why would I reverse a 0 lenght string ?

Comment: Please provide an *actual* MCVE, with a `main` function that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close, you can reverse in the array and add a `'0'` to the beginning with little effort, or you can leave it the way you have it and take care of it in main. Where I think you are getting wound around the axle is in the indexing of `hexadecimalNumber` in your function. While `7` produces *one* hex-digit, it should be at index *zero* in `hexadecimalNumber` (except you initialize `i = 1`) That sets up confusion in handling your conversion to *string indexes*. Just keep the indexes straight, initializing `i = 0` and using `hexadecimalNumber` initialized to all zeros, if you only have a single character at index `1`, pad the string with `0` at the beginning.

Here is a short example that may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NCHR 32

void d2h (int n, char *hex)
{
    int idx = 0, ridx = 0;      /* index & reversal index */
    char revhex[NCHR] = "";     /* buf holding hex in reverse */

    while (n) {
        int tmp = n % 16;
        if (tmp < 10)
            tmp += '0';
        else
            tmp += '7';
        revhex[idx++] = tmp;
        n /= 16;
    }
    if (idx == 1) idx++;        /* handle the zero pad on 1-char */

    while (idx--) { /* reverse & '0' pad result */
        hex[idx] = revhex[ridx] ? revhex[ridx] : '0';
        ridx++;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 7;
    char hbuf[NCHR] = "";

    d2h (n, hbuf);

    printf ("int : %d\nhex : 0x%s\n", n, hbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

The `0x` prefix is just part of the formatted output above.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/h2d
int : 7
hex : 0x07

$ ./bin/h2d 26
int : 26
hex : 0x1A

$ ./bin/h2d 57005
int : 57005
hex : 0xDEAD
```

If you do want to handle the reversal in `main()` so you can tack on the `0x07` if the number of chars returned in `hexadecimalNumber` are less than two, then you can do something similar to the following:

```
void d2h (int n, int *sz, char *hex)
{
    int idx = 0;
    while (n) {
        int tmp = n % 16;
        if (tmp < 10)
            tmp += '0';
        else
            tmp += '7';
        hex[idx++] = tmp;
        n /= 16;
    }
    *sz = idx;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 7, sz = 0;
    char hbuf[NCHR] = "";

    d2h (n, &sz, hbuf);

    printf ("int : %d\nhex : 0x", n);
    if (sz < 2)
        putchar ('0');
    while (sz--)
        putchar (hbuf[sz]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Output is the same**

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Great and comprehensive answer. Thank you